# Maven build error in Azure DevOps Pipeline

Tags: java, azure, maven, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I've try to create a pipeline in Azure DevOps. I'm working with Java and Maven, it's a very basic project, just one class/one method and tests.

I've used the maven pipeline template provided by Azure DevOps, but I got a compilation error :

```
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Source option 5 is no longer supported. Use 6 or later.
[ERROR] Target option 1.5 is no longer supported. Use 1.6 or later.
[INFO] 2 errors 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
```

I don't know what is `Source` and `Target`. I looked at in the `pom.xml` file and in the `azure-pipelines.yml` file, but I saw nothing about `Source` and `Target`.

What is it and how/where can I change it to `6` and `1.6` ?

Furthermore, I'm new with Azure DevOps Pipeline and it's my first project with Maven.

Tell me if you need to see my `pom.xml` file or my `azure-pipelines.yml` file for additionnal information, but there are very basic, I changed nothing (the `pom.xml` file was auto-generated by IntelliJ)

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Have you referenced to this [issue](https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-maven/issues/21)? Please have a try to  add  it  to the pom `<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.6</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.6</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>`. For more information about pom.xml please refer to this [link](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html).

Comment: Thanks, it was that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please have a try to add follow script in the pom.xml file.

```
<properties> 
<maven.compiler.source>1.6</maven.compiler.source> 
<maven.compiler.target>1.6</maven.compiler.target> 
</properties>
```

For more information, please refer to this [issue](https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-maven/issues/21).

Comment: Thanks. But now that it's compiling, I would like to run tests. But maven tells me that no there is no test to run. Any idea ?

Comment: I recommend that you could raise a new SO thread to trace it. And please have a try to add more information (such as the screenshot, .yml file ,etc.) about no tests to run.

Comment: Yes of course I will do it, I just wanted to know if you have just any idea. Thanks for your answer !

Comment: Sorry, as there is no enough information for me, I have no any idea.